# How to properly call and execute a function from a Zustand store?

Tags: reactjs, store, state-management, react-state-management, zustand

I've written out a function below in my Store.tsx component that calculates square footage of a room based on width, length and height. Upon updating my Store file with this component, I get the following error:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLocaleString')"
```

Tried removing the `toLocaleString` from the Results component below, but then the browser crashes. I'm thinking I'm improperly calling `setSquareFeet` in my Results component below, and that may be leading to the crash.

How do I correctly call and execute my store's `setSquareFeet` function in my Result component?

**Store:**

```
const useCalcSquareFeetStore = create<useCalcSquareFeet>((set: any) => ({
  width: 0,
  length: 0,
  height: 0,
  squareFeet: 0,
  setWidth: (value) => set({ width: value }),
  setLength: (value) => set({ length: value }),
  setHeight: (value) => set({ height: value }),
  setSquareFeet: () => { // this is the function I'd like to make work
    set((state: any) => ({
      squareFeet: state.width * state.length * state.height,
    }));
  },
}));

export default useCalcSquareFeetStore;
```

**SquareFeet component:**

```
<Result
  heading="Number of square feet"
  number={setSquareFeet()} // Use the function from the store
/>
```

**Result component:**

```
export const Result: React.FC<Props> = ({ heading, number }) => {
  return (
    <div className="result">
      <h4 className="heading">{heading}</h4>
      <h4 className="number">{number.toLocaleString()}</h4>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

i think u need to do something like this

```
const YourComponent = () => {
  const { setSquareFeet } = useCalcSquareFeetStore();
  // or u can use this
  // const setSquareFeet = useCalcSquareFeetStore(state=>state.setSquareFeet);


  return (
    <>
      <Result
        heading="Number of square feet"
        number={setSquareFeet()} // call your function here
      />
    </>
  )
};

export default YourComponent;
```